# Find the upper and lower bounds of the given quantity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a-b where a=8 to 1 s.f. and b=4.18 to 2 d.p.

1. I thought **a** would be:

Upper:8.5
Lower:7.5

2. And **b** would be:

Upper:4.185
Lower:4.175

However, I am not entirely sure if this is correct nor where to go after this step? Can anyone complete the problem and explain why I am incorrect?

the answer should be:

3.315≤a-b<4.325

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bounds are correct.  The upper bound for $a - b$ is obtained by subtracting the lower bound for $b$ from the upper bound for $a$, which gives $8.5 - 4.175 = 4.325$.  The lower bound for $a - b$ is obtained by subtracting the upper bound for $b$ from the lower bound for $a$, which I will leave for you to complete.

Comment: I corrected an error I noticed.  Now, you should obtain the correct answer for the lower bound of $a - b$.